date conversion and any() in Pony ORM with SQLite
I am building a web application tutorial using Pony ORM. My Python is working, but feels very clunky: in particular, I'm managing date conversion by hand after fetching records, and am doing concatenate-then-split string operations to handle a one-to-many relationship where I would naturally use a JSON field. DB schema, Pony entities, my query, and my conversion code are below; I would be very grateful for advice on how to simplify this.
Database Schema
This database keeps track of which staff members have performed which experiments (many-to-many), which experimental plates are involved in which experiments (many-to-one), and which of those plates have been invalidated (optional one-to-one).
-- staff members: staff_id is primary key
CREATE TABLE staff (
    staff_id BIGINT, 
    personal TEXT, 
    family TEXT
);

-- experiments: sample_id is primary key
CREATE TABLE experiment (
    sample_id BIGINT, 
    kind TEXT, 
    start TEXT, 
    "end" TEXT -- may be NULL if the experiment is ongoing
);

-- join table showing which staff were involved in which experiment
-- there is at least one staff member associated with every experiment
CREATE TABLE performed (
    staff_id BIGINT, 
    sample_id BIGINT
);

-- plate_id is primary key; plate-to-experiment is many to one
- there is at least one plate associated with each experiment
CREATE TABLE plate (
    plate_id BIGINT, 
    sample_id BIGINT, 
    date TEXT, 
    filename TEXT
);

-- invalidated plates (along with who invalidated the plate and when)
-- this table only contains records for plates that have been invalidated,
-- and contains at most one such record for each plate
CREATE TABLE invalidated (
    plate_id BIGINT, 
    staff_id BIGINT, 
    date TEXT
);

Entity Classes
These are straightforward given the table definitions above.
class Staff(DB.Entity):
    staff_id = orm.PrimaryKey(int)
    personal = orm.Required(str)
    family = orm.Required(str)
    performed = orm.Set("Performed")
    invalidated = orm.Set("Invalidated")

class Experiment(DB.Entity):
    sample_id = orm.PrimaryKey(int)
    kind = orm.Required(str)
    start = orm.Required(str)
    end = orm.Optional(str)
    performed = orm.Set("Performed")
    plate = orm.Set("Plate")

class Performed(DB.Entity):
    staff_id = orm.Required(Staff)
    sample_id = orm.Required(Experiment)
    orm.PrimaryKey(staff_id, sample_id)

class Plate(DB.Entity):
    plate_id = orm.PrimaryKey(int)
    sample_id = orm.Required(Experiment)
    date = orm.Required(date)
    filename = orm.Required(str)
    invalidated = orm.Set("Invalidated")

class Invalidated(DB.Entity):
    plate_id = orm.Required(Plate)
    staff_id = orm.Required(Staff)
    date = orm.Required(date)
    orm.PrimaryKey(plate_id, staff_id)

My Problematic Query
I want the following for each experiment:

experiment ID (so that I can construct a hyperlink to the experiment's page)
start and end dates (again, the end date may be None if the experiment is ongoing)
whether or not the experiment has any invalidated plates
the IDs and names of all staff involved in the experiment

What I have found is:

The first three fields (ID, start date, and end date) are easy to get, but I have to convert the two date fields from text to Python date objects after retrieving the values: Pony has a str2date function, but there doesn't appear to be a way to use that inside a query. (Trying to do so produces error messages.)
I was expecting any() and all() functions to go along with Pony's count(), sum(), and other aggregation functions, but they don't appear to exist and Pony rejects use of the built-in functions. I'm therefore using count() > 0 to answer the question, "Have any of the plates in this experiment been invalidated?"
Since several staff may be involved in a single experiment, I am constructing a string with each staff member's ID, personal names, and family name, then using Pony's group_concat() to join those to get a single string in the query result. I then post-process this (strip, split, and convert the ID back to an integer). I realize may actually be necessary because Pony doesn't support nested fields (i.e., doesn't seem to be able to create JSON results), but I'm hoping there's a simpler way.

def experiment_details():
    query = orm.select(
        (
            e.sample_id,
            e.start,
            e.end,
            orm.count(e.plate.invalidated) != 0,
            orm.group_concat(
                f"<{s.staff_id}|{s.personal}|{s.family}>"
                for s in Staff
                if e.sample_id in s.performed.sample_id.sample_id
            ),
        )
        for e in Experiment
    )
    rows = list(query.order_by(lambda eid, start, end, inv, staff: eid))
    reformatters = (_reformat_as_is, _reformat_date, _reformat_date, _reformat_as_is, _reformat_staff)
    rows = [[f(r) for (f, r) in zip(reformatters, row)] for row in rows]
    return rows


def _reformat_as_is(text):
    """Do not reformat (used for uniform zipping)."""
    return text


def _reformat_date(text):
    """Reformat possibly-empty date."""
    return None if text is None else str2date(text)
        

def _reformat_staff(text):
    """Convert concatenated staff information back to list of tuples."""
    fields = text.lstrip("<").rstrip(">").split(">,<")
    values = [f.split("|") for f in fields]
    result = [(int(v[0]), v[1], v[2]) for v in values]
    return result

My thanks in advance to anyone who can help make this simpler—my future students will be grateful as well. If you want the database and code in question, I am gvwilson@third-bit.com.

Please edit you question: What format have the start and end date in the database? Unix timestamp? ISO format? https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES converts string to datetime, see doc
